# How can I update Kendo UI in the Kendo UI Builder?

Tags: kendo-ui-builder

I have created an app using the Kendo UI Builder. It is using Kendo UI version 2016.3.1118. I want to update Kendo UI to the latest version (2017.1.118).

Is there a way I can do this using Kendo UI Builder? Or do I need to manually replace the scripts in the scripts folder and manually change the HTML to point to the new scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Progress will integrate it in next update of Kendo UI Builder. There is no way to change Kendo UI version in the web app, you can just replace files for the new version.